# un-R behaviour of ud.convert()

Tags: c, r, units-of-measurement

Here is a data.frame `df` in which I want to convert the `value` column to *g/g* (grams/gram).The first two entries are in *ug/mg* (micrograms/milligram) and the last two entries are in *ng/mg* (nanograms/milligram). However, the `ud.convert()` function only seems to consider the first unit entry (i.e. ug/mg) it encounters to then convert all `value` entries from that unit, ignoring the change in units in row #3.

```
require(udunits2)

df = data.frame(
  value = rep(1,4),
  unit = c(rep('ug/mg', 2), rep('ng/mg', 2)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df$value2 = ud.convert(df$value, df$unit, 'g/g')
df
#   value  unit value2
# 1     1 ug/mg  0.001
# 2     1 ug/mg  0.001
# 3     1 ng/mg  0.001
# 4     1 ng/mg  0.001
```

Every other R function I can think of does such an operation for each row. Consider `paste()` or `substr()`:

```
paste(df$value, df$unit, 'g/g', sep = '---')
substr(df$unit,1,2)
```

In my opinion this is a very un-R behavior of `ud.convert()` and should be changed or at least a warning should be given. Or am I overlooking something? The conversion happens in the C-function [R_ut_convert](https://github.com/pacificclimate/Rudunits2/blob/master/src/udunits2_R.c). Unfortunately, I don't know any C to propose a change ;)

Comment: The function is in fact not vectorized over the argument `u2`. Some base R functions also have this issue, see for instance the second `rep` example in `?Vectorize`. A solution could be `ud.convert.vector <- Vectorize(ud.convert)` and then use this new function as you would use `ud.convert`.

Comment: great, works! I wasn't aware that one can vectorize a function so easily.